# xpath get value and attribute key

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

Good day! Can anybody help out with parsing the value and key of an attrbute in xml like :

With

```
SELECT xpath('/el:GRID/@*',
'<el:GRID xmlns:el="http://example.com" xmlns:p="http://example1.com" p:title="Joda" p_titler="Dookoo">
    217
    <p:columns>
        <el:GRDCOL p:length="1">226
          <el:BOX p:kory="dory">228
          </el:BOX>
        </el:GRDCOL>
    </p:columns>
</el:GRID>',
  ARRAY[ARRAY['el', 'http://example.com'],array['p','http://example1.com']]);
```

I get `{Joda,Dookoo}`

But I want to get result like :

```
{p:title Joda, p_titler Dookoo}
```

I need it to parse dynamically-created xml, where I do not not know all attributes names...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is how to get name/value pairs for XML attributes:

```
with t(x,ns) as (values(
'<el:GRID xmlns:el="http://example.com" xmlns:p="http://example1.com" p:title="Joda" p_titler="Dookoo">
    217
    <p:columns>
        <el:GRDCOL p:length="1">226
          <el:BOX p:kory="dory">228
          </el:BOX>
        </el:GRDCOL>
    </p:columns>
</el:GRID>'::xml, ARRAY[ARRAY['el', 'http://example.com'],array['p','http://example1.com']]))

select tn.*, tv.*
  from t cross join lateral 
    (select * from unnest(xpath('/el:GRID/@*', t.x, t.ns)) with ordinality) as tv(v,i) cross join lateral
      (select * from unnest(xpath('name(/el:GRID/@*['||tv.i||'])', x, t.ns))) as tn(v)
```

To get desired representation just change `select tn.*, tv.* from ...` to `select concat('{', string_agg(concat(tn.v, ' ', tv.v), ', '), '}') from ...`